# Parse JSON in Bash

Tags: command-line, text-processing, json

I'm making a polyglot program, which takes input and runs files. I would like to run a command for a list of languages. Currently, I only have JavaScript and Ruby supported. My JSON file named `languages.json`:

```json
{
  "langs": ["JavaScript", "Ruby"]
}
```

How would I parse this array from Bash? I would like to echo all languages listed in the `langs` array in `languages.json`, formatted each on a newline. Something like this:

```
Languages supported:

JavaScript
Ruby
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: @steeldriver sorry, forgot quotation marks. I updated it. It's also not really worth it to downvote a question for an error.

Comment: I don't see any downvotes

Comment: @steeldriver huh it was at 1 before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
$ cat languages.json
{
  "langs": ["JavaScript", "Ruby"]
}
```

then using `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.langs[]' languages.json
JavaScript
Ruby
```